# how to check the source code of musl in gdb

Tags: c, gdb, musl

First of all, I don't speak English very well. Please forgive me.
I want to check the source code of musl in gdb.
This is what i have done.

1. apt install musl-tools
2. git://git.musl-libc.org/musl ，i have put it into ~
3. set the path for gdb,below is what in my '/~/.gdbinit':

   ```
   layout src
   directory ~/musl/src
   ```
4. i create a c program:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int main(){
     printf("hello\n");

     return 0;
   }
   ```
5. i compile it with 'musl-gcc -O1 -g3 -static test.c'
6. then i run it with gdb.But when i use 's' to try to step into the source code of printf,it just skip it.

i have tried to ask chatgpt,but still can't solve it.
can anybody tell me why this happen and how can i sovle it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Build musl with debug symbols:

   ```
   $ (cd musl; configure --enable-debug; make)
   ```
2. Build you program against library with debug symbols:

   ```
   $ musl-gcc -g3 -static -Lmusl/lib test.c
   ```
3. Enjoy the sweet success:

   ```
   $ gdb ./a.out
   (gdb) start
   Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x40113d: file test.c, line 4.
   Starting program: /home/allan/a.out 

   Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at test.c:4
   4               printf("hello\n");
   (gdb) s
   puts (s=0x402000 "hello") at src/stdio/puts.c:6
   6       FLOCK(stdout);
   ```

Comment: If that answered your question please accept it by clicking the check mark next to it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, but I did what you said and it still didn't work.

Comment: You need to explain what didn't work.  So delete your old binary and rebuild per above.  Were you able to run gdb and what behavior was different than above?

Comment: I suggest you update your question with a gdb session in (your) step 6 and drop me a comment so I see it.  Add my step 1 as your 2.5 (note that I added make which I forgot earlier).

Comment: I have tried it again and now it can step into the musl-libc source code,thank you so much!
The reseaon why i failed must be i had forgotten the -L musl/lib option why compile the program.Apologize for my carelessness and thank you again for your patience!
Since i am new to statckoverflow.I wonder what should i do now?Do it need to change this question to the successfully running version?

Comment: You revise the question to clarify the problem.  For instance if you have the (failed) gdb session that might be useful context for someone else to search for.  You don't want to fix the problem in your question because that invalidates the answer.  Really, accepting the answer, upvote and comment on answers if you seek clarification is only thing you need to do.  Glad I could help.